# Move a DLL referenced in a UDF to another computer?

Tags: excel, dll, user-defined-functions, vba

Some month ago I wrote some statistical functions in c in Visual Studio, compiled it into a .dll file that I now use in a UDF in Excel. I have once moved the workbook and .dll from one computer to another with success.

But for some reason I am unable to make it work on a third computer and I am unable to figure out why. I get a #value! warning.

The VBA is rather simple:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function kampryk Lib "C:\Users\Anders\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mitprojekt\Debug\mitprojekt.dll" (ByRef p1a As Integer, ByRef p2a As Integer, ByRef s1a As Integer, ByRef s2a As Integer, ByRef ga As Integer, ByRef va As Integer) As Integer

-----

Function kampryk1(p1a As Integer, p2a As Integer, s1a As Integer, s2a As Integer, ga As Integer, va As Integer) As Integer
    kampryk1 = kampryk(p1a, p2a, s1a, s2a, ga, va)
End Function
```

The text in the cells are in form "=kampryk1(1,1,1,1,1,1)"

The folder and .dll exist on this third computer at the same location in the c drive as on the first and second computer as specified in the code. I am using the same 32 bit Excel 365 on all three computers. The only differences I can think of is I am using Windows 7 on the first and third computer and 8.1 on the second.

I really don´t recall doing anything else than moving the folder containing the .dll to the right location when I moved from the first to the second computer so any suggestions on what might be wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Because I have no idea if it is relevant that the .dll was written in C and therefore might be. Per request I have now removed the tag...

Comment: Call the function from the Immediate pane, or from a Sub.  You will likely get a more informative error message.